# Openlayers 2 show pink map (layer) by Iphone

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

My goal is to track my current position by smartphone and show this on the map. For this I'm using openlayers 2.

But now I have the following problem.
When I use the below code in a Chrome Browser (*Desktop, Android*) it works fine. If I open the same page in a iPhone (*Safari, Chrome*) I got always instead of the map just a pink layer with the position marker.

```
  <div id="mapdiv"></div>
  <script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
  
  <script>
  
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");

    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 )
              .transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // Transformation aus dem Koordinatensystem WGS 1984
                map.getProjectionObject() // in das Koordinatensystem 'Spherical Mercator Projection'
              );

    var zoom=16;

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);
    
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
    
    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
    
  </script>
```

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to mixed content, OpenLayers 2 defaults to http for the OSM url, try specifying https

```
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
            "OpenStreetMap", [
                "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                "https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                "https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"
            ]
));
```

Comment: I was able to test it briefly and the map is now displayed. Thank you very much.

Comment: I recently noticed that my http://www.nufosmatic.com was rendering pink tiles in ol2 maps on my iphone (and was working everywhere else). And then I discovered that it also happened with my development server. I was very gratified to find this quick resolution to my silly problem. Three files, three lines of code, and three ol2 map applications are all workie on iphone (again). I am working to upgrade the site to ol6 which does not appear to have this problem. (After... 7 years?... I'm soooo old...)